# Gradle - How do I share an API key set up with the Secrets plugin to CI?

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration

I set up Google Maps for Android according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#step_3_add_your_api_key_to_the_project)

I have an API key in my `local.properties` file. The `Secrets` Gradle plugin is set up and copying `MAPS_API_KEY` to a generated file called `BuildConfig`.

I have CI set up using Bitbucket Pipelines, which is now failing because it doesn't have access to the maps api key. I get the following error when it tries to build:

```
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:40:13-44 Error:
    Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.geo.API_KEY@value at AndroidManifest.xml:40:13-44 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <MAPS_API_KEY> is provided.
```

I tried setting up the `MAPS_API_KEY` as a repository value in Pipelines but that didn't change anything. Is there a "correct" automatic way to share this key? If not, how can I manually set it up in my Continuous Integration system?

Comment: [The secrets github](https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin#cicd-systems) has a section on CI/CD systems, but it's not clear to me how to make a build that actually works. It seems like I could just check in a fake API key, but it won't work for deployment.